# How to connect emulators ( running on local host ) with expo bare app ( running inside a docker container )

Tags: android, ios, react-native, docker, expo

this is my docker file

```
FROM node:20-alpine3.16

WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 19006

CMD [ "npm" ,"start" ]
```

i am able to run metro bundler using this command `docker run -it --rm expo-app` but when i am trying to run android emulator, it throwing this error

```
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /root/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not found: /root/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the Android SDK location.
Error: spawn adb ENOENT
```

then i set an environment variable using this command `docker run -it --rm -e ANDROID_HOME=/users/rahulkumar/library/android/sdk expo-app`  , now it is throwing this error

```
    Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: /users/rahulkumar/library/android/sdk
Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. ANDROID_HOME is set to a non-existing path: /users/rahulkumar/library/android/sdk
Error: spawn adb ENOENT
```

---

if i am trying to run ios simulator than it is throwing this

```
     `Opening on iOS...
✔ Xcode must be fully installed before you can continue. Continue to the App Store? … yes
Going to the App Store, re-run Expo CLI when Xcode has finished installing.
Error: Command failed: open https://apps.apple.com/us/app/id497799835`
```

how can i run my expo-bare app in a docker container with the connection of emulators (on local host ) successfully

Comment: You can not run macOS inside Docker, so you can use Simulator there

Comment: simulator is on local host , is there any way by which we can establish our connection between expo-bare app which on docker with simulators. I looking for a solution which is similar around 'host.docker.internal' that where we use. I really don't know we can do this or not.

Comment: Are you have macOS with iOS Simulator and Expo in Docker?

Comment: Yes , I am using Expo-bare workflow